# JSplitPane not painting correcting

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

In my application, I have a `JFrame` displaying a `JSplitPane`, with the split being `VERTICAL_SPLIT`. The top is displaying a `JLabel`, and the bottom is displaying a `JInternalFrame`. Two problems are occuring.

1. The `JLabel` is displaying, but the `JInternalFrame` is not.

   <s>2. I have to resize the application to have the `JSplitPane` display at all</s>

I believe this is both linked to an incorrect use of `JSplitPane`. However, I have been unable to work out what. May I please have some help with this issue?

p.s. I have run tests to make sure `GUIWindow.getInsideFrame()` is not returning `null`. The `instanceof` checks at the end are saying that both components in the pane exist and are of that type. Thank you very much for all your help:

```
protected static void newWindow(GUIFrame window) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
                JInternalFrame intFrame = window.getInsideFrame();
                pane.setRightComponent(intFrame);
                pane.setLeftComponent(new JLabel(window.getDescription()));
                synchronized(lock){
                    frame.remove(currentPane);
                    frame.add(pane);
                }
                synchronized(lock){
                    frame.revalidate();
                    pane.setVisible(true);
                    frame.repaint();
                    if(window instanceof ColourFrameShower) return;
                    currentWindow = window;
                    currentPane = pane;
                    currentFrame = intFrame;
                }
                if(pane.getLeftComponent() instanceof JLabel) System.out.println("JLabel exists!");
                else System.out.println("JLabel does not exist!");
                
                if(pane.getRightComponent() instanceof JInternalFrame) System.out.println("JInternalFrame exists!");
                else System.out.println("JInternalFrame does not exist!");
            }
            
        });
    }
```

EDIT: I fixed problem 2 with a call to `frame.revalidate()` at the start of the second `synchronised(lock)` block. This has been included in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Did you try to display your JInternalFrame alone, without the JSplitPanel ? Is it working ? :)

Comment: Yes, without the JSplitPanel it is working. See the latest release of the whole application on my github: https://github.com/JD9999/GUI-of-everything

Comment: I've made some tests, trying to reproduce your problem. My label and JInternalFrame just display correctly. Does your JInternalFrame setted to `setVisible(true)` ?

Comment: Thank you sir! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You may need to you address @Kapcash directly with the `@` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in comment, you simply need to use `setVisible(true)` on your `JInternalFrame`, else it will not be considered by your `JSplitPane`.

This a really common mistake on java swing !

I'm glad it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the resizeWeight: pane.setResizeWeight(0.5);

Comment: This didn't do anything for me, but thanks for the quick response! :)